# r_ slicing mistakenly includes last argument

Tags: python, numpy

I have strange float inaccuracies; the results of [`r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) are not consistent:

```
import numpy as np

np.r_[-665.6:-650.24:2.56] == array([-665.6 , -663.04, -660.48, -657.92, -655.36, -652.8 , -650.24])
```

This is not what I expect (the last element is included). Adding `650` "solves" it:

```
import numpy as np

np.r_[-15.6:-0.24:2.56] == array([-15.6 , -13.04, -10.48,  -7.92,  -5.36,  -2.8 ])
```

I believe it is not possible that `np.r_[a:b:t].shape != np.r_[a+x:b+x:t].shape`. Is it a bug and not just inaccuracies? What can I do about it? I use Python 3.11 and NumPy 1.21.6. [Documentation  recommends](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) [`linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) in this case. The API is not the same and the best I can do is:

```
import numpy as np

def float_linspace(start, stop, step, precision=10):
    num_of_elements = round((stop - start) / step, precision)
    new_stop = round(int(num_of_elements) * step + start, precision)
    end_point = new_stop < round(stop, 10)
    coords, new_step = np.linspace(start, new_stop, num=int(num_of_elements) + end_point, endpoint=end_point, retstep=True)
    assert round(new_step, 10) == step
    return coords
```

This is more stable than results from `arange` but I consider it far from elegant.

Comment: `r_` is actually using `np.arange`. Read its docs.

Comment: Your comment doesn't help to answer the question. This bug is the same if you use np.r_ or np.arange. Is there anything about this issue in the doc of np.arange()? I didn't see

Comment: `arange` clearly states that controlling the end point is tricky when using a float step.  It recommends using `linspace`, which in the `r_`  context/notation is an 'imaginary' 'step' value.

Comment: This use of `np.r_` with slice notation is just a notational convenience.  `np.arange` explains the problems with a fractional step, and `np.linspace` has more parameters controlling things like the endpoint.

Comment: Ok sorry, I found the warning in np.arange.
I am not sure what is the best way to convery usage of np.arange with np.linspace, since the last one takes number of elements and not step. What if (stop - start) / step is not integer? I don't think np.linspace can deal with it

Answer (score 1):

These are normal float inaccuracies. You can see this by looking at the last element in your first array more closely:

```py
print(np.r_[-665.6:-650.24:2.56][-1])
```

```
-650.2400000000004
```

One way to avoid these problems is to always use integers for the slicing, e.g.

```py
print(np.r_[-66_560:-65_024:256] / 100)
```

```
[-665.6  -663.04 -660.48 -657.92 -655.36 -652.8 ]
```

For a more general solution, you can use [`np.linspace()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html), as pointed out by @hpaulj in the comments above. The number of elements `num` can be calculated from the `step` size. To mimic the behavior you originally expected, include the endpoint if and only if it is not your original stop value. `math.isclose()` is useful here, to ignore the slight numerical inaccuracies.

```py
from math import isclose

# Your first example
start = -665.6
stop = -650.24
step = 2.56

# General calculation
num, remainder = divmod(stop - start, step)
stop = start + num * step

# Include the endpoint if it is not the original stop value.
endpoint = not isclose(remainder, 0, abs_tol=1e-12)
num = int(num) + endpoint

print(np.linspace(start=start, stop=stop, num=num, endpoint=endpoint))
```

```
[-665.6  -663.04 -660.48 -657.92 -655.36 -652.8 ]
```